# Proof: PTIME not equal EXPTIME

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, exp-time-algorithms

Can someone give me the name of a paper where this is proved or maybe just prove it here (if it's easy enough)?

Answer (score 1):

It follows from the celebrated [time hierarchy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem).